# 'for all' Queries in sql

Tags: sql, database

In class, professor said that SQL language does not provide 'for all' operator.
In order to use 'for all' you have to use 'not exist( X except Y)'

At this point, I can't figure out why 'for all' is same meaning as 'not exist( X except Y)'

I give you example relation:

- course (***cID***,title,deptName,credit),
- teaches (***pID,cID,semester,year***,classroom),
- student (**sID**,name,gender,deptName)

Q: Find all student names who have taken all courses offered in 'CS' department

The answer is:

```
Select distinct 
  S.sid, S.name 
from 
  student as S 
where 
  not exists (
    (select cID from course where deptName = 'CS') 
    except
    (select T.cID from takes as T where S.sID = T.sID)
  );
```

Can you give me specific explain about that?

ps. Sorry for my English skill

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You professor is right. SQL has no direct way to query all records that have *all possible* relations of a certain type.

It's easy to query *which* relations of a certain type a record has. Just `INNER JOIN` the two tables and you are done.

But in an M:N relationship like "students" to "taken courses" it's not that simple.

To answer the question "which student has taken all possible courses" you must find out which relations could *possibly* exist and then make sure that all of them do *actually* exist.

```
select distinct 
  S.sid, S.name 
from 
  student as S 
where 
  not exists (
    (select cID from course where deptName = 'CS') 
    except
    (select T.cID from takes as T where S.sID = T.sID)
  );
```

can be translated as

```
give me all students                    SELECT
for whom it is true:                    WHERE
that the following set is empty         NOT EXISTS
  (any course in 'CS')                  "all relations that can possibly exist"
  minus                                 EXCEPT
  (all courses the student has taken)   "the ones that do actually exist"
```

In other words: Of all possible relations there is no relation that does not exist.

---

There are other ways of expressing the same thought that can be used in database systems without support for `EXCEPT`.

For example

```
select
  S.sid,
  S.name
from 
  student as S
  inner join takes as T on T.sID = S.sID
  inner join course as C on C. cID = T. cID
where
  c. deptName = 'CS' 
group by
  S.sid,
  S.name
having
  count(*) = (select count(*) from course where deptName = 'CS');
```

Comment: I almost understand thanks to you! Then if I change from not exist( ~ ) except( ~ ) to exist(~) except(~) in the example I gave you, the result is the same as "all courses offered except 'CS' department" ?

Comment: No, that's simply "The student has NOT taken all available CS courses." (Of all possible relations, there is at least one relation that does not exist.)

Comment: @onedaywhen "Record" and "row" are equivalent terms. The "type" would be "student" or "course". The relation would be how often they are being related to from another table ("has taken"/"was taken"). I'm not sure why you would think of "data type", as these are completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Let's put the terminology discussion aside. I'm pretty sure you have the formal terminology down way better than me. Point taken. What I was trying to express is that it's easy to determine which relations *do* exist between tables, and it's not as easy to determine which relations *could* exist, but don't, i.e. what the OP's question was about. One can determine *"the student has taken three CS courses"* very easily, trough a simple inner join. Once can't determine "the student has taken all available CS courses" just as easily.

Answer (score 0):

From your table definition and requirement its not clear what is the use of **teaches** table. You want the list of students names those have taken all courses offered by 'CS' department. For this **students** and **course** table is enough.

```
SELECT name
FROM
(
SELECT B.name, A.cid
FROM course A
INNER JOIN student B ON A.deptName = B.deptName
WHERE A.deptName = 'CS'
GROUP BY A.cid, B.name
) A
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(name) >= (SELECT COUNT(cid) FROM course WHERE deptName = 'CS')
```

Internal query just selects all students those have taken any course offered by 'CS' dept and with group by I just make sure that in case a student take same course twice they will be counted as one row. Next I just select those students take all course offered by 'CS' dept.

I think you have some gap to understand your requirement properly. In your requirement no relation with **teaches** table is specified.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: Find all student names who have taken all courses offered in 'CS'
>   department

```
NOT EXISTS returns true if the query passed to it contains 0 records.
```

In this case, your sub-query from NOT EXISTS selects all the courses offered in 'CS', and subtract from this result set all the courses taken by specific student.
If the student have taken all the courses then `except` will remove all and the sub-query will return 0 records, which in pair with `NOT EXISTS` will give you true for specific student, and it will be displayed in final result set.

Answer (score 0):

Brief history: Codd invented the Relational Model (RM), some people created a DBMS loosely based on RM to prove a RM product could be performant, and the SQL language emerged based on that DBMS (i.e. not directly based on the RM).

Codd came up with a set of primitive operators to define a database as being relationally complete. His algebra included `product`, where two relations are 'multiplied' together to give a combined relation; this made it into SQL as `CROSS JOIN`. [Side note: people refer to this operator as 'Cartesian product', which results in a set of ordered pairs. However, `product` in RM results in a relation (as do all relational operators), and `CROSS JOIN` results in a table expression (loosely speaking).]

Codd's algebra also included a `division` operator. I guess the thinking is, we should be able to take the result of `product` and one of the relations and use an operator to result in the other relation. But it does has some practical use too, of course. It is commonly expressed as 'the supplier who supplies all products', after [Chris Date's parts and suppliers database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppliers_and_Parts_database) found in his books. SQL lacks an explicit division operator, so we need to use other operators to get the desired result.

Note there are [two flavours of division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/), being exact division ("suppliers who supply all the parts we are interested in and no more") and division with remainder ("suppliers who supply at least all the parts we are interested in and possibly more"). I tend to be wary of the answers here that do not mention either the name 'division' or that you need to decide whether you need to deal with remainders.

The thinking behind your professor's answer is that a double negative (in mathematics and English) i.e. if the statement "there is no part I don't supply" is true for a given supplier then that supplier will be in the result.

Note there are operators that Codd omitted (e.g. `rename` and `summerize`) that can now be found in SQL, so it's a shame we are still waiting for `division`!